# PHP:Simple Dom Parser Find Nth Element Class Exist

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using the PHP Simple DOM Parser for parsing the HTML Page, Now i am lacking in particular point of how to find the nth element class should be a particular class

For Example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th class="h1">ONE</td>
<th class="h2">TWO</td>
<th class="h3">THREE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="one">Apple</td>
<td class="two">Orange</td>
<td class="null">N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="one">Apple</td>
<td class="null">N/A</td>
<td class="three">Banana</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table looks something like this , so i am traversing the table via tr

```
foreach ($demo->find("tr") as $val) 
{
   if(is_object($val->find('td.null', 0))
    {
      echo "FOUND";
    }
}
```

But the above foreach loop returns "FOUND" if td.null exist.
But I need to find if 2nd element td class is null i need to return as TWO, If third td element class is null i need to return as Three

I hope so that you understand that what i am asking for , so please help me of how to find the nth element class is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what I would do is also iterate each `td`'s thru foreach. So that you'll be able to get which index number key it falls into. (Note that of course its indexing is zero based so it actually starts at `0`).

Then inside the inner loop, just check if the class is `null`, then map it in the corresponding word `1 = one, 2 = two, etc..`.

Rough example:

```
$map = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three');
foreach ($demo->find('tr') as $tr) { // loop each table row
    // then loop each td
    foreach($tr->find('td') as $i => $td) { // indexing starts at zero
        if($td->class == 'null') { // if its class is null
            echo $map[$i+1]; // map it to its corresponding word equivalent
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, this would output `three` and then `two`. Inside the second table row, the `null` lands on the third, inside the third row it lands into the second.

Comment: Thank you ghost from your code i got to work with something like this if($val->find('td', 5)->class =="null") without traversing the td

Comment: @musthafa sure no prob, im glad this was able to get the idea

Comment: And i do no that we can check for the class something like ->class as i am new to DOM parser anyway thanks Ghost

Comment: @musthafa yes you can use that in a couple of this actually, `->id` for the attributes, `->{'data-class'}` you can access the elements attributes with those. it would correspond to its object property

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain to do things like that with simple html dom, if you switch to [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) you will be able to do things like:

```
foreach($demo->find("td.null") as $td){
  echo $td->index;
}
```

as well as lots of other jquery-style things that you would expect in a modern parsing lib.